# Call to undefined function apc_clear_cache()

Tags: php, phalcon, apc, php-7, apcu

I am using Phalcon PHP framework with newly installed PHP 7.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. I also installed apcu and apcu_bc via pecl and I am getting 500 internal error with Apache logging this error:

```
error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apc_clear_cache() in /var/www/html/project/app/controllers/ControllerBase.php:97 ......
```

line 97 of ControllerBase.php:

```
apc_clear_cache();
```

phpinfo():

```
apcu
APCu Support    Enabled
Version 5.1.5
APCu Debugging  Enabled
MMAP Support    Enabled
MMAP File Mask  no value
Serialization Support   php
Build Date  Jul 9 2016 17:22:04
```

Comment: Is the `apc` module also loaded / installed?

Comment: There is no apc module for php 7. Only apcu. That's why there is apcu_bc to have using old code using ```apc_*``` methods with apcu.

Comment: In PHP7 (and anything >= 5.4), you should use opcache instead of APC. http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php  Not sure if Phalcon has support for it though.

Comment: I need APCu as datastore, which OPcache isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok the solution was to rename all the apc_* functions to apcu_* ... I guess the apcu_bc isn't working as it should.